# Pass the live data from nodejs API to an array

Tags: node.js, api, d3.js

I have found an API about theme park wait times. I need to use the live data to do some visualization in d3. My question is how to grab that live data and assign it into an array which I could work with.

Here is the link to the API: https://github.com/cubehouse/themeparks

I tried this:

```
var WaitTimes = disneyMagicKingdom.GetWaitTimes(function(err, rides) {
if (err) return (error);


for(var i=0, ride; ride=rides[i++];) {
    return (ride.name + ": " + ride.waitTime + " minutes wait");
}
});

console.log(WaitTimes);
```

Comment: by using their library

Comment: So, that link shows you sample code from node.js.  Did you try that?  What exactly is your question?  We don't just write whole apps for you here.  You research your topic.  You try some things.  Then, when you get stuck you ask a very specific question while showing us your code and describing where exactly you got stuck.